# FindAllAsync can't find device in windows store app

Tags: winapi, usb, windows-store-apps

The vendor Id and product Id is being passed to FindAllAsync and there is no device returned from FindAllAsync. We've verified that these are the right device IDs and works on other platforms. It's not a plug and play device.

Here is the code below:

```
UInt32 VendorId = 0x1D1B;
UInt32 ProductId = 0x1202;

string aqs = UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(VendorId, ProductId);

var myDevices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

if (myDevices.Count == 0)
{
    return;
}
```

There are no devices found. Any ideas?

---

### Clarification

I should clarify. It's not behaving like it's PNP and not appearing in the device manager in win8 and win7. The device works with a native application for driving the device even though it does not appear in the device manager.

Comment: USB is plug-and-play, so what do you mean by "It's not a plug and play device."  Is this device somehow special or different from other USB devices?

Comment: What kind of device is it? You may need to write a custom driver for it, especially if it is a serial device using the older `usbser.sys` serial drivers (it needs to use the newer `WinUSB.sys`).

Comment: Also note that Windows Store apps also run in a security context that prevents them from using arbitrary devices.

Answer (score 0):

if (myDevices.Count == 0) then you AQS filter doesn't match any device interface in the system.

This means that there are not USB interfaces with VendorId = 0x1D1B & ProductId = 0x1202.

You should probably walk thorough the system device interfaces, and see what they actually are.  I can show you how to do that if you need.